# Как поместить несколько обработчиков на кнопку в Tornadofx (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Наткнулся на 2 события кнопки при использовании TornadoFx: onLeftClick { } и onRigthClick { }. Каждое событие в отдельности отрабатывает как и задумывалось. При одновременном использовании обоих событий - отрабатывает только последнее. Каким образом можно заставить работать оба обработчика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Известный баг в `TornadoFx`.
В случае определения и `onLeftClick` и `onRigthClick` они перекрываются и один переписывает другого.
Как вариант если нужны оба -- использовать `setOnMouseClicked`

```
val clickCount: Int = 1
setOnMouseClicked {
    if (it.clickCount == clickCount && it.button === MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
         // onLeftClick
    }
    if (it.clickCount == clickCount && it.button === MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
         // onRightClick
    }
}
```

Взято отсюда: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/issues/1287